# How do I log out?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have another Stack Exchange account on `Mathematics` using a different email address.

However, I can't switch to it because I can't seem to find the log out/sign out button anywhere.

Can someone help?

Comment: Do you see a button at the top-left, labelled "StackExchange"? Click on it and spot the "Log Out" button.

Comment: @Mico - Oh wow, I honestly didn't see that. I'm normally used to seeing it on the top-right hand corner. Thank you

Comment: I always find it bizarre that some people up-vote *completely off topic* content...

Comment: @Mico Screenshot and answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B - I'm at a site today that won't let me upload screenshots. Feel free to post an answer, though...

Comment: @Mico Nah, take your time ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B - OK, I was able to generate the screenshots and upload them. :-)

Answer (score 5):

First, locate the "StackExchange" button at the top-left of the screen:

[image]

Next, click on the little downward-pointing arrow next to "StackExchange" and bring up the following menu (only the top part is shown):

[image]

Finally, locate the "log out" button and click on it.

Mission accomplished!